# Stored procedure trying to insert in many tables sybase

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

Hello im having issue with my stored procedure. The function of my SP is that it grabs information from different tables and inserts it into a temporary table then, grabs the information from that temporary table  and inserts the info in to many tables.  For better understanding look bellow:

```
   While(condition)
   begin

   select * into #temptable from tableA


       While(condition)
       begin

        insert into table B
        select Column1,Column2 
        from  #temptable 

        insert into table C
        select Column4,Column2,Clumn6
        from  #temptable 

                              While(condition)
                              begin
                                 insert into table F
                                 select Column1,Column2 
                                 from #temptable 

                                 insert into table G
                                 select Column1,Column2
                                 from #temptable 

                                 insert into table H
                                 select Column1,Column2
                                 from #temptable 

                                 insert into table I
                                 select Column1,Column2
                                 from #temptable 


                              end

       end

 end
```

The issue is when it gets to the second while, all 4 inserts work but sometime it only inserts in table F,H,I and not in table G. But if try running the sp again it inserts on all 4 tables(and to make it clear its the same information trying to be inserted always) .Its like if there was some kind of deadlock occurring. Could this be my issue? can there be a deadlock on a temptable? Any help with my issue on my SP.

Thank you all

This is using sybase.

Comment: You have while loops nested three deep? This is going to be slower than molasses sliding across the tundra in January. I would be willing to be that this entire nested loop process can be simplified into 6 inserts with zero looping.

Comment: why don't you use statements with a WHERE clause instead of doing while loops?

Comment: yes there is where  clause but I for to put in a example. The reason for the while loops is because its going to looping through the #tempble each record.

Comment: any help why this is happening?